# Imac g5 with no OS nor CD drive

Tags: boot, usb, mac, cd-image

What I want:

- Ubuntu on a g5 Imac.

What I have:

- An empty PC (Intel g5 17" Imac) with broken CD drive. Its model is A1173.
- This PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and an old Vista partition.
- a usb flash drive.

Problems:

- No CD means the only boot Drive I could use is USB.
- There are no BIOS on Macs so I can't set boot settings or even see if it detects my USB drive. When I start the machine and press ALT the first and only thing I see is an old corrupted winXP partition and not a single option or additional information.
- So assuming blindly that the Mac hardware/firmware works normally, I don't have any Mac OS to use any of the tools that I found on [different tutorials](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) for building a bootable .img drive for macs.
- I can't find much software on Linux/Windows to substitute to those tools, for example among others converting an .iso file (win/linux) to .img (mac I guess). Which makes me think that the scenario where someone like me has Mac hardware but no Mac OS is extremely rare.
- So other than finding someone that has a Mac I have no solution. So I ask what would you do? the only thing is it should not involve any money (I know mac soft is rarely free) which also excludes getting any MacOS unless I can use a free macos.img for VM or restore the original Mac for free.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have an Intel processor or a PowerPC G5?

Comment: On a mac you should be able to boot off a USB stick by pressing U while turning on. Obviously provided you have a suitable USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to another Mac this should be fairly easy. Get a copy of Leopard (the last version that supported PowerPC) in dmg format or if you have the disc great. Next open up Disk Utility on another Mac and restore that `.dmg` file to a USB drive. It is a fairly straightforward process. That drive should then be bootable when holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> during the Mac startup. After this installing Ubuntu should be easy as you will be in Mac OS.

Comment: Will this solution work on an Intel iMac?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if it detects your USB thingy by typing `dev / ls` in **Open Firmware**. Make sure you get the space right for that command. You can get into **Open Firmware** by turning your **iMac** on and holding the power button pressed long after you hear a long beep.